# Solving $\sqrt{\frac{\log\left(x + a + n\right)}{a}} - \sqrt{\frac{\log\left(x + a + n\right)}{x}} = \Phi$ for $x$

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, roots, special-functions

Consider the following equation:

$$\sqrt{\frac{\log\left(x + a + n\right)}{a}} - \sqrt{\frac{\log\left(x + a + n\right)}{x}} = \Phi$$

where all the variables belong to $\mathbb{R}$, and:

- $\log$ is the natural logarithm
- $x \ge 1$
- $a \ge 1$
- $n \ge 0$
- $\Phi$ can be positive or negative

And I'm wondering how to solve for $x$. Even for the special case $n = 0$, I'm not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Where did you found that equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**COMMENT**.- Your equation is equivalent to
$$\log(x+a+n)^{\dfrac{\sqrt{ax}}{2\Phi(\sqrt x-\sqrt a)}}=1\iff(x+a+n)^{\dfrac{\sqrt{ax}}{2\Phi(\sqrt x-\sqrt a)}}=e$$
Keeping into account the data, the only thing I can say is the following:

When $x+a+n$ is exactly equal to $2$, you have $\dfrac{\sqrt{ax}}{2\Phi(\sqrt x-\sqrt a)}\approx1.443$.

When $x+a+n=3$, you have $\dfrac{\sqrt{ax}}{2\Phi(\sqrt x-\sqrt a)}\approx 0.91$

When $x+a+n=5$ you have $\dfrac{\sqrt{ax}}{2\Phi(\sqrt x-\sqrt a)}\approx 0.621$

It seems that if $x+a+n$ is big then $\dfrac{\sqrt{ax}}{2\Phi(\sqrt x-\sqrt a)}$ tends to zero.

Maybe someone else can say something more meaningful. I can not.